# Configuring Subversion (SVN) repository via Apache on Bluehost VPS Server

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, centos6.5

I am trying to configuring Subversion (SVN) on our Bluehost VPS server which has *CentOS v6.5*. So far, Installation went smoothly by following this guide -> http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion

However, now I am stuck at its [4.2 step [Subversion's Apache configs]](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion#head-7d8f5b19ef7e73c2d5f9c614c19b2d1792e90e6b).

Ok so here the story goes.

Mostly on web the guides to install Subversion (svn) on bluehost are for shared server for whom the steps on CentOS official wiki page of [Subversion](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion) (let's call it **A**) doesn't work hence they follow this [guide](http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?12099-Setting-up-Subversion-on-Bluehost) (let's call it **B**).

The module mod_dav_svn allows subverion to be served via Apache, because its installation [is not allowed on shared server](http://phphabitat.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/installing-subversion-svn/) thats what I have learned. Hence many people fall for guide **B**, which can work for us by establishing svn connection over ssh (svn+ssh) however I am trying to bend the spoon to see if svn connection can be established over apache.

Following guide **A**

I have a url `svn.domain.com` pointing to `/home/username/public_html/svn.domain.com/` in which I have setup the repositories named `repos1`

and have setup subversion.conf file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf` as following

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /repos1>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /home/username/public_html/svn.domain.com/repos1
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repos"
        AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

and opening http://svn.domain.com/repos1 it displays plain contents of the directory located in `/home/username/public_html/svn.domain.com/repos1`.

Where I assume it should **ask for password** and display **Revision 0** or at least **trunk**, **branch** and **tag** folders.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

- 1: repos1 folder is created by `svnadmin create repos1` command.
- 2: This setup has worked for us on different server but they have very very limited space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Installing and Configuring Subversion (SVN) on BlueHost VPS Server (CentOS)**

My all steps are just follow up of this beautiful wiki article at http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion . The article has overall 8 steps, however for installation on BlueHost VPS an expansion is required for step 3 and step 4.2

***Step 3*** - While installing `yum install mod_dav_svn subversion` it will give error

```
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 is needed by package mod_dav_svn
```

To resolve it kindly do following steps

```
[$] find / -name "yum.conf"                 --- Note the path
[$] vim /path/yum.conf                          --- Edit the file
```

Remove the `httpd*` from the following line

```
exclude=apache* bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd* perl* php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* ruby* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
```

Save the and exit the file `:wq!`

```
[$] yum install mod_dav_svn subversion      --- If Success, then you can revert back yum.conf file to its original.
```

***Step 4*** - Before proceeding to this step kindly create a domain or subdomain (svn.domain.com) preferable, 
    and assign it to any folder (mostly /home/username/public_html/svn.domain.com)

```
/home/username/public_html/svn.domain.com     --- will be main folder under which I will have many repositories (not just one, but many)
```

***Step 4.1*** - Skip this step from the article, as BlueHost will take its care

***Step 4.2*** - By default Subversion will create a .conf file named as `subversion.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf`

For BlueHost, any files in this path are in-effective (took me four hours to figure out) 
    because it uses C-Panel which has it own requirement to follow -> http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/InsideVHost

So edit the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file in your favourite edit

```
[$] vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`         --- Edit the main Apache config file
[Editor] /svn.domain.com                        --- Hit Enter and search for your domain configurations, scroll through up or down keys or n for next hit
```

Just above the  for svn.domain.com you will come across something similar to below lines

```
# To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
#Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/username/svn.domain.com/*.conf"
```

Uncomment the Include by remove the hash (#) at the beginning and
Copy the path between the Include until *.conf (remove *.conf) and paste as below in `mkdir` command

```
[$] mkdir -p /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/username/svn.domain.com/             --- Creates all parents directory as well if they don't exist
[$] vim /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/username/svn.domain.com/subversion.conf   --- Create subversion configuration file
```

In `subversion.conf` file while in edit mode (press i) paste the below 
and kindly change the path of `SVNParentPath` and `AuthUserFile` as required

*Kindly note that DocumentRoot in VirtualHost configs and SVNParentPath in subversion.conf cannot have same directory path. SVNParentPath must supersede or be in located in different directory altogether, it cannot be under DocumentRoot path.*

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /home/username/public_html/svn.domain.com/
    SVNListParentPath ON
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "DFR Visualization Images Repository"
    AuthUserFile /home/username/public_html/svn.domain.com/svn-auth-conf
    Require valid-user
</Location>`
```

Now `:wq!` and save and exit the file.

Now execute below commands to create the authentication file in the path mentioned in `AuthUserFile` variable in subversion.conf file

In htpasswd command use -cm argument for first time creation of users and for subsequent users just use -m, else previous users data will be lost

```
[$] htpasswd -cm /home/username/public_html/svn.domain.com/svn-auth-conf username       --- Press enter and input password
```

*One more last step.* 
By Default Subversion installs the modules required to load for SVN to work properly in proper directory, but because BlueHost uses C-Panel it has different directory for same purpose, which Subversion will not realise.

Therefore we need to manually copy the Subversion modules installed in default module directory to C-Panel's modules directory.

First find where the Subversion has installed following two modules which we specified in subversion.conf file

```
[$] find / -name "mod_dav_svn.so"           --- Find and note subversion installation path
[$] find / -name "mod_authz_svn.so"         --- Find and note subversion installation path
```

Copy them to C-Panel modules folder (generally `/usr/local/apache/modules/`), kindly verify the path before copying.

```
[$] cp /subversion_modules_path/mod_dav_svn.so /usr/local/apache/modules/
[$] cp /subversion_modules_path/mod_authz_svn.so /usr/local/apache/modules/
```

Now Login to your C-Panel of bluehost and Restart the Apache Service located at 
    `C-Panel -> WHM -> Restart Services -> HTTP Server (Apache)`

Follow the rest steps as in the article.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`<Location "/">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repos"
        AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    <Location /repos1>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /home/username/public_html/svn.domain.com/repos1
   </Location>`

Don't forget to reload Apache.

Comment: tried but still same result

Comment: I think subversion.conf is not loaded at all, because I just enter invalid path for `SVNPath` variable, apache restarted without any errors. Anyways have raised the ticket with Bluehost, will wait for their response as well and update here.

Comment: finally I was able to sort it out with support from Bluehost, thanks for your help though.

Comment: Glad to hear it!